# How to implement a error non-tolerant job in playframework?

Tags: playframework

I use a "Universal" job with @OnApplicationStart to do some initialization work. If any of those failed, play should exit. I tried Play.stop(), but in dev mode, it will restart repeatly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code can do a brute force exit on dev mode:

```
@OnApplicationStart
public class MyCriticalJob extends Job {
  public void doJob() {
    if (!ok()) {
      Logger.fatal("cannot continue due to ...", ...);
      if (Play.mode.isDev()) {
        Runtime.getRuntime().halt(-1);
      } else {
        Play.stop();
      }
    }
  }
}
```